# How do you set a variable to an Edit Text Box

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android developing. I have a value in a variable that I need to set = to a edit text box. How do you do this? I keep getting a null exception error.

```
myStockPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtStockPrice);

ManualPrice = input1.getText().toString().trim();

else if (ManualPrice != null)
    {
    myStockPrice.setText(ManualPrice);

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you get the null exception error?

Comment: This appears as though it would not compile.  Can you perhaps clean it up a bit?

Comment: It compiles just fine. The above code is only a piece. I'm not parsing the variable correctly

Comment: Can you post your debug/crash log?

Answer (score 3):

Hi try this may be in manualprice has no any value so you get a error :

```
 myStockPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtStockPrice);  

    ManualPrice = input1.getText().toString().trim();  

    else if (ManualPrice.length() > 0) 
    {
         myStockPrice.setText(ManualPrice);      
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

myStockPrice could be null because the edittext you are looking for is not in the layout you set with secContentView. is input1 a textview or an edittext? If so check if the belongs to the same layout you set with setContentView.. As others ask you, giving a bit of bt could better help to understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `input1` is not null, this should solve your problem,

```
myStockPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtStockPrice);

ManualPrice = input1.getText().toString();

if (ManualPrice != null)
{
    myStockPrice.setText(ManualPrice.trim());
}
```